# Smoking meat and milk

Tags: halacha, food, cooking-bishul, meat-and-milk

It says in [SA YD Siman 87 Sif 6](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A4%D7%96_%D7%95) that if one "smokes" together a meat and milk or if they "cook" it in the hot springs of Teveria then they are patur (however this is still ossur to do and of course eat.)

In the Sefer Chedrei De'ah ([See here Sif 6)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=8137&st=&pgnum=53) he writes that the process of smoking that one would be patur if done is only when the smoke is NOT yad soledes bo. However if it would be yad soledes he writes that this is "c'risichas aish gomer" (like a boiling fire.)

How is this understood? The point of the Shulchan Aruch to tell us that if you "smoke" meat and milk together that you are patur is to say that it's not "derech bishul" (the normal way of cooking.) But it would seem simple that the smoke must be yad soledes in order to do something to this mixture. If the smoke is cold (or at least not yad soledes) then one could say that this case would be perhaps muter completely or at least not ossur b'dieved.

Are there any additional sources that speak about this (that either go with the opinion of the Chedrei De'ah or argue)?

Comment: Didn't the Be'er Heitiv say its assur to smoke and chamei teveriah is assur mdrabbanan?

Answer (score 1):

The Oirah Vesimcha on the Rambam (Ma'acholos Asuros 9:6) says the same thing:

> המעושן. כתב בפרישה (סי' פ"ז ס"ק ט') פירוש מעושן שנתחממו בשר בחלב בעשן כמו בחמי טבריה [ר"ל שהיה הבשר והחלב בתוך הקדירה ומתחת הקדירה לא היה אש אלא עשן חם עובר מתחתיה וכך נתחממו ונתבשלו], או י"ל שנשרה בחלב ואח"כ תלאו בעשן ע"כ, ונראה יותר כפירוש הב' דאופן הראשון נראה שהוא בישול גמור דהא קיי"ל לגבי שבת תולדת אור כאור וא"כ העשן לא גרע מתולדת אש, ומה לי נתחמם ע"י אש ממש או תולדת אש, וגם מסתבר דעשן יש לו דין אש ממש ולא תולדת אש, אלא א"כ נכבה האש לגמרי דאז לא הוה אלא תולדת אש.‏