# Cold smoking and kashrut

Tags: kashrut-kosher, cooking-bishul, meat-and-milk, issur-vheter

[related](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27649/smoking-meat-and-milk)

[Cold smoking](https://www.forfoodsmokers.co.uk/acatalog/proq-eco-cold-smoke-container-smoker-generator.html) is a process by which food is cured by contact with smoke which fills the whole vessel but does not [ideally] exceed 80˚F, which is well below yad soledet (at least for my hands) so that there is no issue of *zeiya* (steam). However, due to the cooking method, rei'ach is likely exchanged to some degree.

Do the poskim discuss whether the same smoker may be used (at different times, with cleaning) for both milchigs and fleischigs, based on the above factor?

---

Note: the above-linked question appears to assume simultaneous cooking, while this question does not.

Comment: Is reicha ever a problem for keilim?

Comment: @DoubleAA, the question is whether the smoke transfers reichot from the meat to the walls of the smoker, which would then be re-transferred to the food. See Kouty's answer which says that it appears to be a non-issue in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`However, due to the cooking method, rei'ach is likely exchanged to some degree.`

Let's start with the problem of Reach (odour, smell) in Gemara.

See Pesachim 76ab:

> אמר רב בשר שחוטה שמן שצלאו עם בשר נבילה כחוש אסור מאי טעמא מפטמי מהדדי ולוי אמר אפילו בשר שחוטה כחוש שצלאו עם בשר נבילה שמן מותר מאי טעמא ריחא בעלמא הוא וריחא לאו מילתא היא ‏
>
> Rab said: Fat meat of a [ritually] slaughtered [animal] which was roasted together with lean meat of nebelah is forbidden. What is the reason? They fatten each other. But Levi maintained: Even lean meat of a [ritually] slaughtered [animal] which was roasted together with fat meat of nebelah is permitted. What is the reason? It is a mere smell, and smell is nothing.

#### So we know yet

1. that there is some problem with smell from a non-kasher meat that
   may alter the kasher meat when both are rosted together, a problem of "givin the taste" based on the prohibition of Taam Keyikar
2. and we know also that two opinions exist, Rav prohibited this and
   Levi allowed (for Levi, the smell does not rise the degree of "Taam").
3. We see too that even if the "prohibited/prohibitant" meat is less
   fatty, Rav prohibits.
4. We see also that smell which goes from one food to another when they are roasted at the same time is discussed only, so the intensity of contact is relatively strong.

> עביד לוי עובדא בי ריש גלותא בגדי ודבר אחר
>
> Levi gave a practical decision at the house of the Resh Galutha in the case of a goat and 'something else.'
>
> מיתיבי אין צולין שני פסחים כאחד מפני התערובת מאי לאו תערובת טעמים וקשיא ללוי ‏
>
> An objection is raised: One may not roast two Passover offerings together, on account of the mixture. Surely that means, the mixture of [the] flavours, which is a difficulty on Levi's view?
>
> .... לימא תיהוי תיובתיה דרב אמר רבי ירמיה הכא במאי עסקינן כגון שצלאו בשתי קדירות בשתי קדירות סלקא דעתך אלא אימא כעין שתי קדירות  דליכא תערובת טעמים ‏
>
> we say [then] that this is a refutatio of Rab? - Said R`Jeremiah: The case we discuss here is e.g. , where he roasted them in two pots... when there is no mixture of flavours.
>   [You say] '
>   In two pots - can you think so! - Rather say, as though [they were roasted in] two pots,

#### New informations:

1. Th smell prohibited by Rav is for Rav a strict equivalent of prohibited taste,
2. But this kind of taste, passing through air does not contaminate from a food in one container to an other food in an other container.

> ... תני רב כהנא בריה דרב חיננא סבא פת שאפאה עם צלי בתנור אסור לאכלה בכותחא ההיא ביניתא דאיטווא בהדי בישרא אסרה רבא מפרזיקיא למיכליה בכותחא מר בר רב אשי אמר אפי' במילחא נמי אסורה משום דקשיא לריחא ולדבר אחר: ‏
>
> Rav Kahana the son of Rav Hinena the Elder recited: A loaf which was baked together with roast [meat] in an oven may not be eaten with kutah. A fish was roasted [i.e., baked] together with meat, [whereupon] Raba of Parzikia forbade it to be eaten with kutah {Milkshik}. Mar B`R`Ashi said: Even with salt too it is forbidden, because it is harmful to [one's] smell and in respect of 'something else.' {harm of mixture of meat and fish}.

#### In conclusion.

It seems that the Talmud concludes according to the view of Rav. Two foods coocked in a same oven gives taste one to another, but not if they are in separated containers.

1. Tosfot said in Name of Rabenu Tam rules explicitly as Rav, but specifie that in a great oven, the taste of the odour is not sufficient from the halachic point of view. The rule is only for small oven and non-covered food (similarly to 2 containers)
2. But Rashi ruled as Levi because of the view of Rava in Masechet Avoda Zara ([66b](http://dtorah.com/otzar/shas_daf.php?ms=Avodah-Zarah&df=66b)), which is congruent to Levi opinion.
3. Shulchan Aruch and Rama [YD 108, 1](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x4322) rules as Levi Bedieved, and enumerate several conditions in which we allow Lechatechilla.

#### The OP is about

`the same smoker may be used (at different times, with cleaning) for both milchigs and fleischigs`

1. The Rema [YD 108, 1](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x4322) said that, for a non simultaneous utilisation of the oven, when there is no "perspiration/exsudation", it is allowed for a standart oven. A frociori for the cold smocker.
2. The Shach SK 12 said in name of the source of the Rema (Tshuvot Maimoniot), that the containers can not absorb the odour and later exsude it again.

`does not [ideally] exceed 80˚F (= 26˚ Celsius), which is well below yad soledet` 
I don't know any source for the existence of recha at cold temperature. for liquid, there is Kavush, but for odour. no source.

### Summary

It is correct to use the smoker at different times for milchig and fleishig if you are sure that there is no zea. Additionnally, if there is zea, may be that the coldness of the process may not extract taste from foods themselves, but only product a kind of smoke.