# Is nonkosher taste OK?

Tags: kashrut-kosher

If kosher food happens to sit in the presence of nonkosher food and thereby acquires some of its flavor, is it still kosher?  (In general, it is not possible to completely shield food from surrounding smells and aromas.)

Comment: What do you mean? Hot vapors from non kosher food together with kosher food in the same oven? That would not be kosher indeed. You should clarify what you mean by “sit”. Contact or not? Hot or cold?

Comment: ריחא מילתא.........

Comment: No contact.  Just aromas in the air.

Comment: Check out https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De'ah.108.1

Comment: @kouty, I thought we pasken ריחא לאו מילתא, at least מעיקר הדין

Comment: See my post I edited now. I think that if he wants it it's achshevei

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/73266/9215

Comment: The halacha is that *taam k'ikar* - if a food's taste is discernibly improved by nonkosher, the food is also nonkosher.

Comment: @Loewian the halakha is also that _reicha lav milta_ - if just the smell transferred, then it is still kosher. Which case is this?

Comment: My (limited) understanding of the sugya is that we generally assume that, at least after the fact, the minute amount of invisible airborne particles of nonkosher that are transmitted without visible steam (i.e. via *reicha* -scent alone), are not expected to significantly improve the flavor of the kosher food, at least in typical ancient settings. A modern day freezer, or similar airtight storage unit, might over time impart more flavor that the units of yore, at least over a long period of time -though likely that would still be excused as *notein taam lifgam*-detrimental taste contamination.

Comment: @loewian if you can source that reicha is a just the same rule as taam lifgam then you might have the makings of an answer, but then I don't understand what Rav and Levi were arguing about.